# German keyword search - look for every possible combination

Tags: r, nlp, keyword

I'm working on a project where I define some nouns like `Haus, Boot, Kampf, ...` and what to detect every version (singular/plurar) and every combination of these words in sentences. For example, the algorithm should return true if a sentences does contain one of : `Häuser, Hausboot, Häuserkampf, Kampfboot, Hausbau, Bootsanleger, ...`.

Are you familiar with an algorithm that can do such a thing (preferable in R)? Of course I could implement this manually, but I'm pretty sure that something should already exist.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to avoid numerous false detections, you first need an algorithm that can separate compound words. E.g., there are many syllables ending with "h" in German and "aus"  is a word too. Thus, a compound word can contain the string "haus" but not the syllable "haus".

Comment: If using Python for parts of your code is an option, you could use a pretrained model for compound splitting like https://github.com/dtuggener/CharSplit (note that you might have to call this repeatedly on smaller parts). You could try to combine that with a lemmatizer (or if you're only working with nouns a stemmer will work as well) that supports German such as (NLTK)[https://www.nltk.org/] or (SpaCy)[https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features].

Answer (score 0):

you can use `stringr` library and the `grepl` function as it is done in this example:

```
>   # Toy example text
>    text1 <- c(" This is an example where Hausbau appears twice (Hausbau)")
>    text2 <- c(" Here it does not appear the name")
>   # Load library
>     library(stringr)
>   # Does it appear "Hausbau"?
>     grepl("Hausbau", text1)
[1] TRUE
>     grepl("Hausbau", text2)
[1] FALSE
>   # Number of "Hausbau" in the text
>     str_count(text1, "Hausbau")
[1] 2
```

Comment: this does not answer my question. In your case, the exact keyword is given. However what I want is to detect the singluar/plural version of given keywords in addition to any possible compound words

Comment: You can define a vector with the singular and plural of those words you are interested in. For example `grepl(c("car","cars"), text1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
check <- c("Der Häuser", "Das Hausboot ist", "Häuserkampf", "Kampfboot im Wasser", "NotMe", "Hausbau", "Bootsanleger", "Schauspiel")
base <- c("Haus", "Boot", "Kampf")

unlist(lapply(str_to_lower(stringi::stri_trans_general(check, "Latin-ASCII")), function(x) any(str_detect(x, str_to_lower(base)) == T)))

# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Breaking it down**

Note the comment of Roland, you will match false TRUE values in words like "Sc**haus**piel"

You need to get rid of the special characters, you can use `stri_trans_general` to translate them to Latin-ASCII

You need to convert your strings to lowercase (i.e. match Boot in Kampfboot)

Then apply over the strings to test and check if they are in the base list, if any of those values is true. You got a match.